# Puzzled about the coroutine of tornado

Tags: python, tornado, coroutine

I am trying to figure out the flowing code in gen.py of the tornado.

```
    future = TracebackFuture()
    if replace_callback and 'callback' in kwargs:
        callback = kwargs.pop('callback')
        IOLoop.current().add_future(
            future, lambda future: callback(future.result()))

    try:
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    except (Return, StopIteration) as e:
        result = getattr(e, 'value', None)
    except Exception:
        future.set_exc_info(sys.exc_info())
        return future
    else:
        if isinstance(result, types.GeneratorType):
            try:
                orig_stack_contexts = stack_context._state.contexts
                yielded = next(result) # A (mark)
                if stack_context._state.contexts is not orig_stack_contexts:
                    yielded = TracebackFuture()
                    yielded.set_exception(
                        stack_context.StackContextInconsistentError(
                            'stack_context inconsistency (probably caused '
                            'by yield within a "with StackContext" block)'))
            except (StopIteration, Return) as e:
                future.set_result(getattr(e, 'value', None))
            except Exception:
                future.set_exc_info(sys.exc_info())
            else:
                Runner(result, future, yielded)
            try:
                return future
            finally:
                future = None
    future.set_result(result)  # B
    return future
```

I have two functions.

```
@coroutine
def foo():
     #do something
     bar = yield bar()
     #do something else

@coroutine
def bar():
     #do something
     return [1,2,3,4]
```

Then, call the `foo()` function, the code run to the point marked A. Function `bar()` will be called and because `bar()` is not GeneratorType it will run like a normal function.  Next, set future result and return future.  This point that set result before return future is most confusing. After `bar()` return the future, `foo()` get this future, but the future has set_result done before it handled by `io_loop.add_future`.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was so stupid for ignoring the code:

```
if self.handle_yield(first_yielded): 
       self.run()
```

if the future is done, the value will be sent to the corresponding generator.